# Animate function call subtleties

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a callback possible after an animation is complete.

```
pieceimg.animate({path:path}, {duration:2000*path.length,  //120
                               step:path.step,
                               easing:"linear",
                               complete:function() {
                                                     if (finalcallback)                
                                                         finalcallback(); 
                                                   }
                });
```

path is a simple javascript "class" which has some prototype functions defined correspondingly.

When does the `complete` call happen here? Is is at the end of every step (but then `step` is supposed to called too)?

I have some animation in the `finalcallback()` function. It gets triggered before this animation is complete. Need help!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be having problems because your animation isn't animating a css property.

Take a look at [this example](http://gnarf.net/special-fx/textAnimation.html) that I used in my [presentation](http://gnarf.net/special-fx/#text-animation) at the 2011 jQuery Conference in Boston.

Animate is pretty picky / tied into CSS properties so you need to set some fake property to 0,  so that it detects it as "animatable".

In your example, only one "frame" of the animation ever plays because it doesn't detect the `path` property as something it can animate.

Comment: Quick question: I am changing the css position inside the 'step' function. Would jQuery still have the problem of detecting it as animatable?

Comment: Its the `{prop: path}` part of it that I think might be causing you issues... try `prop: 1` You might want to try making an example of this code (not) working on http://jsfiddle.net